# How to find how many closed geodesics are on a Surface of Revolution?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I'm confused how I'm supposed to find the amount of geodesics given only the description of the surface of revolution?

I can parametrise the surface with $x(u,v) = (v\cdot cos(u), v\cdot sin(u), \frac{1}{v^2})$

Comment: What have you been studying in class? You need to think about what tools you have to approach this.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm trying to solve it using the definition of a geodesic as a curve with the second derivative perpendicular to the Tangent space, and the resulting First Fundamental Form coefficient relation for that. Are there other things I should be looking at?

Comment: You can write down the standard 2nd order ODEs for geodesics, but that won't be very enlightening. That will never help you decide about closed geodesics. I suggest you look for results about geodesics on surfaces of revolution, specifically, and possibly the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem.